# Elopy and probabilities

Tags: python-3.x, probability

I've installed Elopy and I'm trying to understand how the probabilities it computes work.

In fact I do not understand the results it gives me.

I use this very basic script :

```
from elopy.elo import Elo

teama = Elo()
teamb = Elo()
print(teama.win_probs(teamb, is_home=True)) #0.64
print(teamb.win_probs(teama, is_home=False)) #0.5
```

I do not understand why one team (the visitor one) has 50% chance to win the game while the other, which is at home, has 64% chance of winning the game.

I've looked on the internet and I found that maybe the probability which is returned by `win_probs` is in fact the probability of winning and tying the game but I'm not sure about it. If it's the case then it could explain these strange results I get.

Comment: The elopy library use formula available from https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-we-calculate-nba-elo-ratings/ .   I just examinated the code from https://github.com/mcbarlowe/elopy/blob/main/elopy/elo.py

Comment: @StéphaneRigaux I read once again the code but I still can't understand  why f(A)+f(B) > 1 for the same match. Where A is the victory of team A and B the victory of team B and f the function to compute the % of win